# Scrolling UIScrollviews inside UITableviewcells together

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` that inside each cell there is an `UIScrollView`. when 1 `UIScrollView` is moving, all the `UIscrollViews` in all the other `UITableViewCell` are forced to scroll to the same x.

This works great except that the `UIScrollView` animation is not working smoothly, when scrolling the scroll stop the second the finger leave the screen instead of slowing down like the normal scroll animation.

Inside `scrollViewDidScroll` i change the other `UIScrollViews` using:

```
for cell in self.sportTable.visibleCells {
            if scrollView != (cell as! MySportCell).scrollView {
                (cell as! MySportCell).scrollView.setContentOffset(self.currentPointInDetailedScroll ?? CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: false)
            }
        }
```

what i'm basically trying to get is that all the `UIScrollViews` in all the `UITableViewCell` will move together and when scrolling and lifting the finger all the `UIScrollViews` will slow down instead of just stoping and looking like it got stuck

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused after reading your question. If you want to scroll smoothly, it's easy. Just depend on the scrollview.

Listening to scrollview change events and let other scrollviews do the same scrolling.

[image: Sample to scrolling]

1. when a scrollview begining scroll, record it! (And then everyscrollview else should do the same from him)
2. when the scrollview just recorded changed, let all other scrollview change too.